# converting OSB to Camel/Spring

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, apache-camel, osb

I have inherited a large body of OSB code. I want to move to a free platform such as the offerings from Apache. Is this an easy thing to do? What sort of pain would I expect?

Regards, Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were reasonably proficient in OSB already, then you shouldn't have huge issues with the easiest 80%. I mean, OSB is validation, enrichment, routing, transformation and operations on (by default) SOAP messages; it's not rocket science. If you were *really* keen, you could probably parse the .proxy files and convert the obvious bits of it to Camel to save you some time.

The problem is not with the business logic per se (assuming a like-for-like replacement), but with the non-functional expectations of the infrastructure. Enforcing any SAML policy you care to think of, extreme fault tolerance in the XML it accepts, handling throttling both inbound and outbound, zero-downtime deployments, clustered result caching etc are the kind of things that you won't discover the SOA solution relies upon until you start looking.

In short, the problems won't be development-related, but architecture- and design-related.

Comment: thanks Trent. I'm looking at a big re-architecturing anyway as a way to reduce running costs. What I do't want to do is change for the sake of change.